# How to compute multiple ranks of a player with one request?

Tags: sql, postgresql, request

I'm using PostgreSQL and I would like to get a list of all the player's rank from one table.

For example, I have this table "Scores" : (the combination user_id - battlefield_id is unique in this table)

```
+----------+----------------+-------+
| user_id  | battlefield_id | score |
+==========+================+=======+
| Legolas  | Helm's Deep    | 42    |
+----------+----------------+-------+
| Legolas  | Pelennor       | 100   |
+----------+----------------+-------+
| Gimli    | Helm's Deep    | 43    |
+----------+----------------+-------+
| Gimli    | Pelennor       | 120   |
+----------+----------------+-------+
| Aragorn  | Helm's Deep    | 50    |
+----------+----------------+-------+
| Aragorn  | Pelennor       | 10    |
+----------+----------------+-------+
```

And I would like a request to compute all the ranks of Aragorn on any of the battlefields and return this kind of result :

```
+------+----------------+
| rank | battlefield_id |
+======+================+
| 1    | Helm's Deep    |
+------+----------------+
| 3    | Pelennor       |
+------+----------------+
```

I currently have this request who works well but I have to specify both the user and the battlefield :

```
SELECT count(*)+1 AS rank FROM scores WHERE score < 
(
    SELECT score FROM scores WHERE user_id = 'Aragorn' AND battlefield_id = "Pelennor"
)
AND battlefield_id = "Pelennor"
```

But I have no idea how to adapt that to get the rank on any battlefield.
I don't have to manage ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number`, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qcfT5GBxhFd6wq6Kniim7x/3)

```
select
    rnk,
    battlefield_id
from
(

  SELECT
    user_id,
    battlefield_id,
    row_number() over (partition by battlefield_id order by score desc) as rnk 
  FROM scores 
) val
where user_id = 'Aragorn'
```

Output:

```
| rnk | battlefield_id |
| --- | -------------- |
| 1   | Helm's Deep    |
| 3   | Pelennor       |
```

Comment: Sorry, the output was supposed to be :
| 1    | Helm's Deep    |
| 3    | Pelennor       |

I made a mistake

Comment: @OtterWorld updated my answer and demo link, please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your version *with a correlated subquery*:

```
SELECT s.battlefield_id, count(*) AS rank
FROM scores s
WHERE s.score <= (SELECT s2.score
                  FROM scores s2
                  WHERE s2.user_id = 'Aragorn' AND
                        s2.battlefield_id = s.battlefield_id
                 )
GROUP BY s.battlefield_id;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `scores(user_id, battlefield_id)`.  On a large set of data, it would be interesting to compare the performance of this to the `row_number()` version.  This might have a performance advantage.

Comment: Thank you I keep that in mind too. The base will have millions of entries, and the request multiples join and parameters. I'll test both of them.
A ``group by s.battlefield_id`` is missing at the end to make it works though

Comment: @OtterWorld . . . Did you compare the performance (with the index)?